# Google OAuth 2.0 web application looking up redirect URIs for the wrong project

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-authentication

I'm trying to build a web application in Django which requests users to manage their calendars using the Google Calendar API. I'm following the steps described in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer, but in Django instead of Flask.

So far, I've written a view called `google_calendar()` which gets an authorization URL and redirects to it:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow


# Client configuration for an OAuth 2.0 web server application
# (cf. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)
CLIENT_CONFIG = {'web': {
    'client_id': settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    'project_id': settings.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    'auth_uri': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    'token_uri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
    'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
    'client_secret': settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    'redirect_uris': settings.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URIS,
    'javascript_origins': settings.GOOGLE_JAVASCRIPT_ORIGINS}}

# This scope will allow the application to manage your calendars
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']



def get_authorization_url():
    # Use the information in the client_secret.json to identify
    # the application requesting authorization.
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_config(
        client_config=CLIENT_CONFIG,
        scopes=SCOPES)

    # Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
    # the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required.
    flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000'

    # Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
    # Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
        # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
        access_type='offline',
        # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
        include_granted_scopes='true')

    return authorization_url, state


def google_calendar(request):
    authorization_url, state = get_authorization_url()
    response = redirect(to=authorization_url)
    return response
```

However, if I navigate to this view, I get a 400 error:

[image]

The URL is not fully legible here, but if I copy-paste it into my browser, I get redirected to a different project, called "NPS Survey", from the one I intended (which is called "Cleo"). I then get an error message because I have scheduled that project for deletion:

[image]

I'm quite sure I entered the keys, etc. for the Cleo project and not the NPS Survey one. Why are the redirect URIs being looked up for the wrong project?

Answer (score 1):

`flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000'` This uri means after user authenticate successfully, google IDP would redirect to. Apparently, you make it redirect to `http://localhost:8000` in google identity provider. It's "NPS Survey".

You should set as `flow.redirect_uri = 'http://yourhostip:8000'`. And also set `http://yourhostip:8000` on google oauth side about redirect url.

Comment: I was actually running this script on my localhost, so the redirect URI was the intended one. In the end, the problem resolved itself after the removal of the "NPS Survey" project was finalized; I still don't know why it was defaulting to the wrong project initially, though.

Comment: Although you run script on your localhost, but you send `flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000'` to google IdP, you tell google IdP that redirect after authentication to "localhost:8000", to google's "localhost:8000", which is wrong. As google message "localhost:8000 does not match the ones authorized for OAuthe client"

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app, "For testing, you can specify URIs that refer to the local machine, such as `http://localhost:8080`". So I don't agree that 'localhost' in this context refers to Google's `localhost` as you assert.

Comment: If you run IdP on your localhost, the "localhost:8000" would work. If you use google Oauth service， I insist my opinion.